# discord.py how do I check how many messages were sent within a time period

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, timeout, spam-prevention

I am new to discord.py. I want to know if there is a way to check how many messages were sent within a time period by a user

For example, if someone sends 5 messages in a span of 4 seconds, I would like to know how to get my bot to respond to this. This is for a very specific anti-spam (not a built-in one)

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried so far and why doesn't it work? Please [edit] these details into your question; SO is not a code writing service - see [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [AutoModRule](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AutoModRule) object for spam moderation.

To get the messages a user has sent in a channel you can use this.

```
channel = discord.TextChannel() # The channel to check.
user = discord.User() # The user to check.
seconds = 5 # The seconds ago to check messages.

import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

messages = 0

async for message in channel.history():
    if message.author == client.user:
        message_time = message.created_at.timestamp()
        if message_time > now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds):
            messages += 1
```

This gets the text channel history (all of the messages) and uses each messages `message.author` and the client's `client.user` attributes and compares them to see if the user sent the message and adds them to a counter.

If you want to check all channels in a guild you can use `guild.text_channels()` which returns a list of text channels.

Note: This uses `message.created_at.timestamp()` to normalize the time to the system time and might be able to be replaced with `message.created_at` see [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5921) for more information.

Comment: Why is `seconds` a string?